# In a paper whose I am the sole author, should I use "I" or "we"?

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style

When writing a paper whose I am the sole author, should I use "I" or "we" when referring myself?

Comment: I have been in the same situation, and I always use "we".  The reason being I would personally find it incredibly distracting to see the word "I" written in a research paper -- I imagine it would suddenly read like a high school report.